# Display WooCommerce Login Errors Inline

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to display form validation errors inline below each input on the WooCommerce user login form.

Is this possible without going the route of testing against the values in the array returned by `WC()->session->get('wc_notices')` and then rending custom message depending on the value?

Comment: This is an old thread but wondering if you figured this out?